# Являются ли данные дополнения однородными, чтобы перед каждым "и" поставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

"Она была украшена золотыми арками и арками из драгоценных камней и колоннами из ляпис-лазури". Возможно, однородными являются только "арки", и тогда запятые не нужны...

Comment: Она была украшена золотыми арками и арками из драгоценных камней, и колоннами из ляпис-лазури. (http://www.treismorgess.ru/?p=761)

Comment: Не совсем понимаю: для чего зпт перед "и колоннами"? В этом исходнике оч много ошибок, поэт ориентир-ся на него точно не стоит.

Comment: А я не понимаю, зачем первое "и". Если для украшения, то можно было ранее и ещё одно поставить.

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от того, считает ли автор, что два первых однородных члена представляют собой группу. Я вижу только два корректных варианта.

Первый вариант:

**Она была украшена (золотыми арками и арками из драгоценных камней) и колоннами из ляпис-лазури.**

Второй вариант:

**Она была украшена золотыми арками, и арками из драгоценных камней, и колоннами из ляпис-лазури.**

Comment: Я именно на них и зависла. Текст датир-ся примерно 7-м веком до н. э., поэтому до автора не достучишься...

Answer (score 1):

**Она была украшена золотыми арками, и арками из драгоценных камней, и колоннами из ляпис-лазури.**

Два повторяющихся союза И, запятые ставятся.

Группировка однородных членов нежелательна, так как в предложении **явно присутствует перечисление, которое подчеркивает все элементы**, использованные для украшения.